# MySQL REGEXP Match two spaces or nothing

Tags: mysql, regex

```
Stringy: 5/5
Stringy : 3 / 5
3 / 5  Stringy
```

I'm trying to match two leading spaces on a string, or ignore it if not found. I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM testtable
WHERE `file` REGEXP '(  )Stringy(: | : )'
```

This doesn't return any rows though

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify: you are fine with that you will only get a Boolean result with REGEXP / RLIKE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape characters which have special meaning in regular expression pattern such as the brackets `(`, `)`.

Example with two leading spaces:

```
SELECT "  Stringy: 3/5" REGEXP '[ ]{2}Stringy(: | : )';
## 1
SELECT "  Stringy : 3 / 5" REGEXP '[ ]{2}Stringy(: | : )';
## 1
```

and a maximum of two leading spaces:

```
SELECT "Stringy : 3 / 5" REGEXP '[ ]{0,2}Stringy(: | : )';
## 1
```

See also the

- [MYSQL Docs on Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)
- [Escape special characters for SQL REGEXP](http://davidchambersdesign.com/escape-special-characters-for-sql-regexp/)